# Combinatorial proof of a nice expression for Stirling numbers of second kind

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinatorial-proofs, stirling-numbers

While answering a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923973/count-all-possible-routes-between-restaurants-and-apartments) I came across the following nice identity:
$$
\sum_{1\le k_1\le k_2\le\dots\le k_n\le m}\prod_{1\le i \le n}k_i={n+m \brace m},
$$
where ${n+m \brace m}$ refers to the Stirling number of second kind. The equation can be readily proved by using generating functions but I strongly suspect that there should be a simple combinatorial explanation of the expression.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Just an observation, I don't know if it helps or not, and maybe you know that already. Your LHS is Vieta's formula LHS for a polynomial with roots $1,2,\ldots,m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**  Consider the following algorithm:
You have a list of the $n+m$ numbers and you start with $\{1\}$ as the partition, you start also with a pointer starting at $2$ that is going to increase $n$ times and in each number you have the following decision to make: If the number of blocks is exactly $m,$ you have $m$ options per number. If not, you can decide if you want to append the number to a block or create a new block where the number is going to be the smallest element of the block. When this happens the number of blocks will increase.  
As an example and for simplicity, assume $m=2$ and take $n=3.$ We start with $1$ and we place it in a block so $\{1\}$ is what we have. Then $2,$ if we decide to place $2$ in the other block, then we will end up having $2^3$ options for the rest of numbers. If we decide to place $3$ as the smallest element of the new block, we will have $2^2$ options and so on. So we will have
$$\sum _{i=0}^{3}2^i=2^4-1=LHS,$$
but of course every partition can be created in this way. There you can check that this is the correspondence
$$\underbrace{1^3}_{\{1,2,3,4\},\{5\}}+\underbrace{1^2\cdot 2}_{\{1,2,3,\cdots \},\{4,\cdots \}}+\underbrace{1^1\cdot 2^2}_{\{1,2,\cdots \},\{3,\cdots \}}+\underbrace{ 2^3}_{\{1,\cdots \},\{2,\cdots \}}$$

So, to generalize, consider **where** do the numbers change, so I would suggest you write the LHS as
$$\sum_{d_1+d_2+\cdots +d_m=n}1^{d_1}2^{d_2}\cdots m^{d_m}.$$

Here the $d_i$ represent the frequency of $i$ in the sequence $k$ i.e., $$d_i = |\{j:k_j=i\}|.$$

A way to understand this algorithm is to think about it backwards. Suppose I give you a partition $\pi \vdash [n+m]$ with $m$ blocks. Suppose the blocks are labelled $\pi =\{B_1,\cdots , B_m\}$ where
the blocks are ordered by their minimal elements $b_i\in B_i: 1=b_1<b_2<\cdots<b_m\le n+m$. Consider further the consecutive differences of these numbers $d_i=b_{i+1}-b_{i}-1\ (0<i<m)$, $d_m=n+m-b_m.$ Notice that $d_i\ge0$ and $d_1+d_2+\cdots +d_m=n+m-(m-1)-b_1=n$. Notice further that $d_i$ is essentially the number of elements which can be placed arbitrarily in any of the first $i$ blocks, so that there are $i^{d_i}$ ways to perform this.

Comment: Could you clarify the connection between $a_i$ and $k_i$?

Comment: @user I have edited it to explain. Hope it helps.

Comment: This helps a bit, but I still struggle to understand the next argument ("you will place ..."). It would be nice if you expand the explanation.

Comment: @user I have edited with some kind of reciprocal argument that will explain what I wrote before. Hopefully I made this clear :).

Comment: I have edited you answer in a way that it becomes understandable to me. Please check.

Comment: @user Seems good to me, sorry about my english. I am trying to improve in this website.

Comment: English was not the main issue here. :) I was quite sure that you approach is correct but it was not obvious to me that this algorithm is a rigorous way to obtain all possible partitions of a set of $n+m$ objects into $m$ non-empty subsets.

Comment: This comment aims to clarify the construction (after two years I was not able to comprehend it immediately). It is in my opinion simpler to think from the very beginning about $m$ blocks with distinct starting elements (numbers). The first block starts always with $1$, whereas there are alltogether $\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}$ ways to choose the remaining $m-1$ starting elements. There remains $n$ numbers after this procedure. Any of these $n$ remaining numbers can be then put in any block **with a smaller starting number**.

Comment: The claim is that the above construction creates all possible distinct partitions of a set of $n+m$ objects into $m$ non-empty subsets. The construction described in the text does not guarantee that one ends with $m$ blocks (for example all elements can be placed in a single block).